# Porque el xmlwritter omite datos a la hora de guardar en xml?

Tags: c#

tengo varios objetos en una clase a partir de un archivo xsd y tengo el siguiente objeto por poner un ejemplo:

```
    FacturaElectronicaResumenFactura resumen = new 
    FacturaElectronicaResumenFactura()
        {

            CodigoMoneda = FacturaElectronicaResumenFacturaCodigoMoneda.CRC,
            TipoCambio = 1m,
            TotalServExentos = 1m,
            TotalMercanciasGravadas = 1m,
            TotalMercanciasExentas = 2000m,
            TotalGravado = 1m,
            TotalExento = 2000m,
            TotalVenta = 2000m,
            TotalDescuentos = 1m,
            TotalVentaNeta = 2000m,
            TotalImpuesto = 1m,
            TotalComprobante = 2000m

        };
```

Y quiero guardarlo en un xml para lo cual tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FacturaElectronica));
    var ruta = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + 
    "//SerializationOverview.xml";
    System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(ruta);
    serial.Serialize(file,fe);
    file.Close();
```

pero cuando abro el xml para revisar, algunos datos o propiedades definidas en la clase FacturaElectronica no se guardan. Porque no se estan guardando todas las propiedades del objeto en el archivo xml, alguna idea???

---

@Salvador Navano funciono como veras sigue omitiendo nodos
        -

```
     -<LineaDetalle>

     <NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea>

    <Cantidad>1</Cantidad>

    <UnidadMedida>kg</UnidadMedida>

    <Detalle>detalle</Detalle>

    <PrecioUnitario>2000</PrecioUnitario>

   <MontoTotal>2000</MontoTotal>

   <SubTotal>2000</SubTotal>

   <MontoTotalLinea>2000</MontoTotalLinea>

   </LineaDetalle>

   </DetalleServicio>


   -<ResumenFactura>

   <TotalVenta>2000</TotalVenta>

   <TotalVentaNeta>2000</TotalVentaNeta>

   <TotalComprobante>2000</TotalComprobante>

    </ResumenFactura>
```

Comment: Podes mostrar tu xml?

Comment: y habria que ver tu clase, la definicion de la misma

Comment: Intentas serializar `FacturaElectronica` pero el objeto que muestras es de tipo `FacturaElectronicaResumenFactura`, debes serialiazar el mismo objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente la clase generada a través del archivo XSD no tiene todas las propiedades necesarios para hacer la serialización de manera adecuada, tales como SerializableAttribute, XmlTypeAttribute y/o XmlRootAttribute. Para asegurarte de ello, microsoft hizo una herramienta que convierte el XSD a una clase con todo lo necesario (omite esta parte si ya lo realizaste):

1. Ejecuta el comando en tu consola de windows para ir al directorio donde se encuentra la aplicación **xsd.exe**. Dependiendo de la versión que tengas de VS este directorio puede variar.

> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools

2. Ejecuta el comando para convertir el XSD en una clase (este comando tiene variantes e incluso puedes generarla en C#, por tu código voy a dejarlo en VB). Estoy tomando en cuenta que tu archivo es **FacturaElectronicaResumenFactura.xsd** y está en el directorio **E:/xsd/**

> xsd.exe E:\xsd\FacturaElectronicaResumenFactura.xsd /classes /language:vb /out:E:\xsd\

Con esto obtienes una clase en el mismo nombre en el mismo directorio con extensión .vb.

Ahora para la serialización, yo lo he realizado con el siguiente código. Que ademas utiliza hace override del encoding que genera el **StringWriter** y lo setea como utf-8

```
Private Function ParseFacturaToXML(ByVal _factura As FacturaElectronicaResumenFactura ) As String
    'Serializa el objeto en un string xml
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(FacturaElectronicaResumenFactura ))
    Dim textWriter As New Utf8StringWriter()
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, _factura)
    Dim sXML As String = textWriter.ToString()

    Return sXML 
End Function

Public Class Utf8StringWriter
    Inherits StringWriter

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Encoding As Encoding
        Get
            Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

En la salida del método ParseFacturaToXML deberías de ver el string del XML y ya puedes usarlo para guardarlo en un archivo como lo estabas haciendo.

Comment: Gracias salvador nava. Ya lo del xsd ya lo habia hecho exactamente asi. Voy a probar con ese metodo para ver si funciona.